# In C, is it possible to integrate new code in a running process by recompiling a dynamic library?

Tags: python, c

I am picking up C in order to speed up some bits of a large python project. In order to add new functions to a continuously running python script, I have it occasionally check a .py file and integrate it's contents.  I was wondering if there was a way of doing the equivalent in C.  Is there a way to have it pick up the contents of a dynamic library on the fly?

Comment: Have you considered using http://cython.org/ or http://pypy.org/ instead to speed up the code that needs attention?

Comment: @ChrisProsser. I had considered pypy, but this was a good excuse to learn C. I may actually go with cython when I get a handle on C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to use [`dlopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) to access the library rather than linking at compile time, then `dlsym` to access functions within it. To switch to a new library you'll need to `dlclose` the handle and create a new one - wrapping this in a module to handle all of it is not a terribly difficult task.

Comment: Using `dlclose` in a running process may be tricky. You must be sure there are no references to the old library (e.g. a pointer to a static variable in it).

Comment: It seems worth mentioning to me that although you could link any lib you like and as long as you know the symbol name get a reference to any of its functions, you **need to now** the functions signature in advance if you want to sucessfully call it.

Comment: Not actually true. In theory you could have a single defined function signature which provides the signature of the rest of the module as well as adaption data that your loader module then parses + uses. It would be large and unwieldy, but you could do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in windows with [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[FreeLibaray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I am sure there is a unix equivalent.